# Exactly how fast is Ludicrous Speed?

Tags: spaceballs

In the hit movie Spaceballs, Spaceball-1 goes beyond 'Light speed', beyond 'Ridiculous speed' and into '[Ludicrous Speed](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LudicrousSpeed)'.

But precisely how fast *is* Ludicrous Speed? Are there any contextual clues within the film or interviews from the cast/crew that give a more accurate reckoning?

Comment: As good as the movie was; it pretty much avoided following any rules of physics. I really don't think it's possible to give an accurate answer.

Comment: It's beyond hilarious. Beyond ridiculous, even. But slower than plaid.

Comment: @onewho - We shall see. You'd be surprised what people can turn up if they go looking.

Comment: One of the characters was a talking pizza... I very much doubt there'll be anything resembling an answer for this.

Comment: In which case, the statement "No, there are no such contextual clues" would be a perfect answer.

Comment: I'll have to dig out my copy of Spaceballs: The Book to see if it gives any further information.

Comment: Only if there was someone who could read and search the novelization.

Comment: @Zikato - I've not got it...

Comment: @Omegacron so the Goosebumps guy wrote [Spaceballs: The Book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/710542.Spaceballs#)... I feel like I should have known that! I have roughly 3,000 Goosebumps books in my attic

Comment: @Richard - I have it, but it's lost somewhere among a few hundred other books out in my storage building. I MIGHT feel like going through them this weekend, but when I get home in the evenings I just want rum, WoW, and sleep.

Comment: @onewho - Au contraire. Using logic, we can actually narrow the figures down quite closely.

Comment: I'm sorry for being that person, but the semi-colon after the word "was" in the first comment is really ugly.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - You could try flagging it with a custom reason. Perhaps a mod will change it for you...

Comment: Ludicrous speed is about as ludicrous as this question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Based on the [movie script](http://sfy.ru/?script=spaceballs), we can actually set an upper and lower bound on "ludicrous speed" at **somewhere between 65 and 1380 times the speed of light**.

---

The majority of the action in Spaceballs takes place within the Druidia system. After making good her escape from her wedding, Princess Vespa is attacked by Spaceball-1 somewhere past the orbit of Jupiter 2. During this incident, the Spaceballs flagship goes to "*ludicrous speed*" for a total of approximately 1 minute. After achieving a full stop, the ship then turns around and heads for one of the moons of Vega (still evidently within the Druidia system).

Corporal Asshole identifies that their return journey will occur **within the day**:

> **SANDURZ:**  *Good work. Set a course, and prepare for our arrival.*
>
> **HELMET:**  *When?*
>
> **CORPORAL:**  ***Nineteen-hundred hours, sir.***

Their outward journey was 1 minute, their inward journey will be between 60 and 1380 minutes. Assuming that they plan to make the return journey at light speed, and that that journey will take them between 1 and 23 hours, we can peg a lower and upper bound on the speed of "ludicrous speed" at somewhere around 65 and 1380 times the speed of light.

Comment: What makes you say that Jupiter 2 and the moon of Vega are in the Druidia system? Also, what about Barf's line "They must of overshot us by a week and a half"?

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I presumed that they meant that it would take a week and a half to return at normal (light-)speed

Comment: Since they're taking inspiration from Star Wars, I don't think we can necessarily assume "light speed" should be taken literally (since in Star Wars they use that term for travel much faster than the speed of light). And even if it is taken literally, you could imagine that even if they weren't willing to try ludicrous speed again, ridiculous speed might be OK.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - The crew seem very surprised at the idea of exceeding light speed.

Comment: How does "between 65 and 1380 times the speed of light" answer the quest9io, which asks ***"exactly"*** and ***"precisely"*** how fast is it? Is it a rule on this site that words like "exactly" are just there for decoration?

Comment: @user14111: Lol. The question describes the criteria for an ideal answer; it doesn't mean that incomplete answers are not allowed. The [Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers) both indicate that partial answers can be helpful.

Answer (score 41):

It is two steps up from light speed, the second step being "Ridiculous Speed".

[image]

Comment: Well yes. Very clever.

Answer (score 6):

In the audio commentary of the DVD, Mel Brooks describes *Ludicrous Speed* thusly;

> *"So we went from light speed to ridiculous speed, and then finally to ludicrous speed, which is **probably faster than the speed of cash registers."***

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does he mean the speed of the machines themselves, or is he referencing the speed of the line at checkout? Either way, it's subjective, which would actually be a pretty creative form of saying that *Ludicrous Speed* is the [Speed of Plot](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TravelingAtTheSpeedOfPlot).

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd While the latter can frequently be described as "ludicrous," it can hardly be described as "speed."

Comment: @DavidW You replied while I was editing my comment

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the full quote.

Comment: More seriously, I read his (still wisecracking) meaning as something like "faster than we can whip up merchandising sales!"

Answer (score 5):

#### No. There are no contextual clues.

Having read [the script](http://www.evilwillalwaystriumph.com/script.htm), I can safely say the precise speed is never mentioned or discussed in any way.

Comment: what about in the Extended SpaceBalls Universe????!?

Comment: @Oldcat Mel Brooks has never accepted the ESU as canon.

Comment: There was a sequel in the offing..

Comment: @InguShama he wrote the animated series if im not mistaken.

Comment: I find it amusing that one day after you left this comment, someone chimed in with the very contextual clues that you claimed didn't exist.